# Show and Hide UL Tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<nav class="menu" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Content</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Files</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a href="#">Site</a></li>             
  </ul>
</nav>
```

With the following CSS styles:

```
nav ul ul {display: none;} // Hides the child menus
```

And the following JQuery code:

```
$('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function () {
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

Which should toggle the visibility of the child menus.

However, when I click the "Content" A tag the next UL does not show.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/YxZH8/

Comment: @JasonP strange, I copied his code and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/HHVMu/

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: Oh, forgot to include jQuery. Maybe OP forgot the same.

Comment: May be you didn't add JQuery library.

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors. Are you sure you included jQuery, and is your code below the DOM elements or in a DOM ready handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work just fine for me :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

It correctly toggle the ul menu next to `<a href="#">Content</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ... I posted in my initial question that I had:

```
nav ul ul {display: none;}
```

But in fact I had the following:

```
nav ul ul {display: none !important;}
```

I was using a "Hide" LESS mixin for it and didn't realize it ...

But isn't it strange that using important stops Jquery Toggle from working?

Comment: _Isn't it strange..._ - No, because jQuery just toggles the display (or maybe visible) property. The `!important` overrides what jQuery does.